# Using Okhttp.MockebServer for testing websocket

Tags: junit, okhttp, mockwebserver

I am using okhttp.MockWebServer to test rest api calls.
Is there a way to use it for mocking a websocket call as well?

Essentially, I have a ws client (Client extends WebSocketListener) which calls an external websocket server and gets back responses asynchronously.
I want to mock this server so it can be used for junit test.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the tests in https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/f8fd4d08decf697013008b05ad7d2be10a648358/okhttp/src/test/java/okhttp3/internal/ws/WebSocketHttpTest.java

```
  @Test public void serverMessage() {
    webServer.enqueue(new MockResponse().withWebSocketUpgrade(serverListener));
    WebSocket webSocket = newWebSocket();

    clientListener.assertOpen();
    WebSocket server = serverListener.assertOpen();

    server.send("Hello, WebSockets!");
    clientListener.assertTextMessage("Hello, WebSockets!");

    closeWebSockets(webSocket, server);
  }
```